# How to redirect multiple values to a script at different times from a single file

Tags: bash, unix, io-redirection

I want to redirect multiple values to a script from a single file from the command line. This script will ask different values from the user and runs accordingly. Script will use `read` command to read values from user. All i want to do is instead of asking different values from the user it reads those from a file. I want to run like this:

```
run-iso.sh abc.iso <filename
```

and my file contains following,

yes

10.168.10.206

25

1

And i don't want set any delimiter in my script to read these values.It should read as it reads from stdin. Is this possible? Correct me if my question itself is wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain, what is not working with your approach?

Comment: thanks for replay.i forgot to mention that run-iso.sh script will do md5 iso media check which can abort by press esc key from the user(any way i don't want to do so).Now Problem here is after showing prompt to enter first value it stops there itself.I don't understand how this read command behaves with my txt file.actually read will complete its action only after press enter key.so is this the reason behind it or something else that i didn't understand??

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).

> Expect is a program that "talks" to other interactive programs
>   according to a script

This way you could script the call to `run-iso.sh`. [Here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/) you find some easy examples!